# Why inheritance doesn’t work inside methods?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, c++17

This does not compile:

```
struct Base
{
    void something( int a ) { }
};
struct Derived : public Base
{
    static void something()
    {
        std::unique_ptr<Derived> pointer = std::make_unique<Derived>();
        pointer->something( 11 );
    }
};
```

It’s possible to fix with `using Base::something` but still, is it possible to make inheritance work as advertised even inside methods?

Comment: notice that the function in `Derived()` is `static` while the function in `Base` is not, so it doesn't override it. Also, even if the function in `Derived` were not static, the function in `Base` needs to be declared `virtual` to be overrriden

Comment: I think the question is asking why `Base::something(int)` is not automatically accessible from `Derived:::something()`.

Comment: What's "advertised"? And by whom?

Answer (score 2):

By using the same name for the function in the derived class you **hide** the symbol from the base class.

You can solve it by pulling in the name from the base class with the `using` statement:

```
struct Derived : public Base
{
    // Also use the symbol something from the Base class
    using Base::something;

    static void something()
    {
        std::unique_ptr<Derived> pointer = std::make_unique<Derived>();
        pointer->something( 11 );
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish.  I added `virtual`, and changed the name of the Derived `something` class function, and put in two variants.  One variant calls through virtual inheritance, the other calls Base class member function directly.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

namespace {

struct Base {
    virtual ~Base();
    virtual void something(int a) { std::cout << "Base a:" << a << "\n"; }
};

Base::~Base() = default;

struct Derived : Base {
    void something(int b) override { std::cout << "Derived b:" << b << "\n"; }
    static void action() {
        std::unique_ptr<Derived> pointer = std::make_unique<Derived>();
        pointer->something(11);
    }
    static void other_action() {
        std::unique_ptr<Derived> pointer = std::make_unique<Derived>();
        pointer->Base::something(11);
    }
};

} // anon

int main() {
    Derived::action();
    Derived::other_action();
}
```